# Test JSON with spec2 in Scala

Tags: json, scala, lift, specs2, lift-json

I'm trying to test a Json with Specs2 but I always get a parse error.

Maybe because I use a JObect?

```
val j: JObject = "hello" -> "world"
j must */("hello")
```

this is the error:

Search_fields

```
Could not parse:
JObject(List(JField(hello,JString(world))))
java.lang.Exception: Could not parse:
JObject(List(JField(hello,JString(world))))
    at net.liftweb.echidnasearch.QuerySearchSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$124.apply(QuerySearchSpec.scala:496)
    at net.liftweb.echidnasearch.QuerySearchSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$124.apply(QuerySearchSpec.scala:485)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

MatchQuery
```

thanks

Comment: is this a compile-time error, or runtime (spec2)? Paste the full exception, please.

Comment: thanks @VasyaNovikov exception updated

Comment: again, is this a compile error, or a runtime?

Comment: Sorry @VasyaNovikov is a runtime error!

Answer (score 1):

specs2 json matchers are `Matcher[String]`. I suspect that what you are seeing is an attempt to parse the `.toString` representation of the Lift Json object which is not parseable by the specs2 matcher. You should match instead against a proper String representation of the Lift Json object.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a compile error, then check all imports and try again:

```
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
import net.liftweb.json._
val t:JObject = ("a" -> "b")
```

I tried this in the console, it works:

```
scala> val t:JObject = ("a" -> "b")
t: net.liftweb.json.JObject = JObject(List(JField(a,JString(b))))
```

Comment: i've the same situation. In compilation i don't have errors. My problem is in runtime.

Comment: I don't know the syntax of spec2, but something like this should work: `t.\("a") should === "b"`. In your code, I see the word "world" only once (shouldn't it be compared to?), and I don't see the method ".\" at all.